# Cannot access roaming settings when UI dialog open

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I can access the roaming settings from the side panel in the outlook Add-in.But when I am trying to access roaming settings if the UI dialog ( [DialogAsync](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.displaydialogasync?product=access)) is open. It getting as undefined.

```
var _settings = Office.context.roamingSettings;
var numberDetails = _settings.get('PHONENUMBERSLIST');
```

Answer (score 4):

There are only two Office.js APIs that can be called in the dialog:

- messageParent
- isSetSupported

See the note about 1/3 of the way down in the is article: [Use the Dialog API in your Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins)

Comment: Thanks, Is there any other way to check roaming settings inside the dialog?

Comment: Could you share some additional information around your scenario? What information do you need from Roaming Settings in the dialog?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I need to check some previous saved properties ( roaming settings ) when UIi dialog is open

Comment: There are two ways you could pass information to the dialog box. Add query parameters to the URL passed to displayDialogAsync or store the information in a place that is accessible to both the host window and the dialog.  For more information check out this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#pass-information-to-the-dialog-box.

Answer (score 2):

`RoamingSettings` will be only available in the frame that created it. If you need to share some values between your dialog and side panel, you can pass these values as parameters in url:

```
var url = new URI('Dialog/myDialog.html').absoluteTo(window.location).toString();
url += '?myvalue=' + Office.context.roamingSettings.get('myvalue')
        + '&othervalue=' + Office.context.roamingSettings.get('othervalue');
var dialogOptions = { width: 20, height: 35, displayInIframe: true };

Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, dialogOptions, function (result) {
    settingsDialog = result.value;
    settingsDialog.addEventHandler(Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, receiveSettingsMessage);
    settingsDialog.addEventHandler(Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogEventReceived, settingsDialogClosed);
});
```

Then, in your dialog, you can use them or set them again inside `$(document).ready()` using `getUrlParameter('myvalue')`.

You can also send needed values back to the side panel using:

```
function sendMessage(param) {
    Office.context.ui.messageParent(JSON.stringify(param));
}
```